# Typo on wikipedia input/output examples

Tags: c++, cout, flush

I am reading the following [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_(C%2B%2B)#Examples) from wikipedia.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The article reads then as:

> This program would output "Hello, world!" followed by a newline and
>   standard output stream buffer flush.

I do not believe this is correct, since a `std::flush` is not required on `'\n'`.

Should I go ahead and edit the article changing the `'\n'` into `std::endl` ?

Comment: apparently, on a question of the type "is X true", downvotes are no longer used to say 'bad question', but to say 'no'

Comment: I think @sp2danny was being a bit sarcastic. Downvotes *shouldn't* be used to indicate that the answer is "no". (But we don't know the reason for the downvote.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, standard output is flushed when the program terminates normally. (If a simple "Hello, world" program terminates *abnormally*, there's probably not much you can do about it.) You might want to clarify that point, though (that the flush happens at the end of the program, not on the `std::cout << ...` call).

And the `return 0;` is unnecessary (but harmless).

Comment: I believe you need to reword `program terminates`, I believe flushing only occur when no abnormal program termination occur (abort...).

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `cout` stream is synchronized with the C library's `stdout` stream (i.e. they will share the same buffer). And the C standard specifies that `stdout` will be line-buffered or unbuffered when writing to an interactive device.

What this means is that by default, `cout` will flush when printing `\n` if the output is an interactive device such as a console. If you call `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false)`, it may not flush anymore.

Additionally to this, the output will be flushed at program termination as the other answer says.

Comment: most c++ library re-uses C's stdout, but this is not *required*

Comment: @malat It is required by the standard.

Comment: isn't that the whole purpose of `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` then ?

Comment: @malat I'm not sure what you are referring to by "that". `sync_with_stdio(false)` will cause the C++ streams to act independently of the C library's streams, but the default is that they are synchronized.

Comment: ok I missed the whole point, you meant to say "this is required by default"

Comment: It's required unless you specifically call `std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false)` to disable it.